# Spring Data MongoDB, orm vs json

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, hibernate

So, here is my conundrum ...
I am used to building Spring MVC RESTful web-services on the back-end.  I usually use a SQL relational database like Oracle, Postgres, MySQL.  I use the latest hibernate, I use hibernate annotations, I create all my entities and Dao's and everything is fine in this ORM manner.

I am working on a side project where we'll be consuming several different web-services from other vendors.   They all have very different data all in JSON format.  And we know ... the data in the JSON format will probably change over time.

We want to put this all into a NoSQL database, and we're going to be using MongoDB.  This will be my first foray into using a NoSQL database, and so I've been doing research on Spring Data MongoDB.

Spring Data MongoDB seems like it wants to use a hibernate-like model with POJO's ... but I know the JSON data I import will never seem to fit a POJO model.  There also seems to be this other complaint against SD MongoDB that when you go to pull the data, you pull an entire document and all it's sub-structures with it ... I don't know if any of this is true or unfounded.

What I want essentially, is ONE MongoDB collection (table) to store this JSON data.

Say Vendor data looks like this:

```
Vendor 1   {"a":1,"b","2","c":3}
Vendor 2   {"x":"x1","y","y22","z":"z333"}
Vendor 3   {"aa":11,"bb","22","cc":33}
```

Then I want the one collection to have the following fields:

```
   a : 1
   b : 2
   c : 3
   x : x1
   y : y22
   z : z333
```

etc .... and aggregate of all the fields.

I've seen where we can go from a MongoDB 'DBObject' to JSON and from JSON back to a 'DBObject' ... but I am not sure if that would work?   I look forward to testing it.

So, if anyone has any experience storing multiple different JSON inputs into one table, or collection, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example, you're merging all vendors properties into one document. MondoDB will not do that automatically for you just by adding the new values to "the one collection" (sic), you know? You'll have to find an unique document and add the new properties to it each time.

Comment: Oh .... I guess I have my nomenclature wrong.    I'd like to have one collection (table) and every JSON data that comes in would be it's own document (row) with those fields from that JSON data.   So, we'd have one document/row with fields a,b,c and another document with x,y,z etc ...  So, every time I get a piece of JSON data, I can turn that into a DBOject I guess and write a new document to the collection ... is that correct?    In this way, I don't know if I would need Spring Data?  I probably would need a DAO layer to do CRUD though.